# Should I always use Command even though it might not be necessary?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

Should I always use Command even though it might not be necessary?

Or should I only use Command in the case where more things, menu items, buttons,
whatever, when clicked execute the same code?

Maybe it is good practice to always use Command, or maybe it adds additional
unnecessary complexity. I am new to WPF so please share some advices.

Comment: Use commands only for input alike things. User changes something and you delegate the command. Btw the namespace of the commands tells you when you shall use them. Its System.Window.Input.

Comment: Not sure I understand. What type of inputs do you specifically mean?

Comment: User input. Like clicking, typing...etc.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get it. But you can do the same things with click events. My question was why prefer Command.

Comment: Click event must be handeled in code behind and in WPF you dont want to use code behind. Thats why you shall use Commands which allow you to handle user input in your ViewModel. Do you know about MVVM pattern?

Comment: I have read about it, but I can't claim I really understand its power since I have not used it in practice. Anyway, clicking and keyboard is all the user will do with my app, so that means I should go 100 % with Command and never use click events? I think this is what you suggest?

Comment: Bingo. You got it. Use MVVM, Bindings and Commands and you will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the MVVM pattern, which is mandatory in every serious WPF application, 'ICommand' is the way to go for every action that is not purely interface logic.

I'll explain:

As you probably know, the MVVM pattern distinguishes between Model, ViewModel and View, where the ViewModel mediates between Model and View. The ViewModel usually holds all the data which is consumed by the view and which you bind your view to. The important thing is:

> The View is agnostic of the ViewModel

This means, although your View is bound to the ViewModel, it doesn't reference it, there is no logical dependency to the ViewModel. The 'ICommand' bridges this gap: It kind of packs an action into a bindable property. That's the main point, probably:

> A command wraps up an action or function into a WPF databindable
>   property

And as databinding is the mechanism which, in MVVM, View and ViewModel are connected with each other, the command is the vehicle to perform **every** action, no matter if it is triggered by one control or by many, that transcends the sphere of pure UI (which is almost everything):

Have a look [here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx), where this image is taken from:

[image: MVVM]

If you don't use MVVM I'm not sure whether you need commands at all. There is no significant difference to WinForms then, regarding the UI event handling. But again: MVVM and WPF go hand in hand, in my opinion.

Comment: For beginner it is hard to grasp what really is view, viewmodel and model. Is this correct? View = Window + other controls. ViewModel = Properties + Commands + Data Bindings. Model = more complex classes and methods that implement the business logic.

Comment: Well, more or less: DataBindings are defined in the View, not in the ViewModel. The actual binding (technically) is neither View nor ViewModel, but 'WPF magic'. MVVM is quite a challenging concept, to get started I recommend taking some time, a good book, do some tutorials, etc. You wont learn it quick and dirty... It's worth it, though!

Comment: Is it a few days to learn thing, or more like few months getting used to?

Comment: Really hard to say, it depends on your experience and how deep you need to get into it. For the basic principle and a simple app you'll need a couple of days until you feel more or less comfortable. To build a line-of-business software it's month until you get all the concepts and best practices, but that is not only due to the complexity of MVVM, but WPF in general... Just a really ruff guess...